# Grover algorithm in Q#

Tags: programming, grovers-algorithm, q#

I have this program derived from Microsoft Quantum Kata for quantum search (Grover algorithm) (see [here](https://gist.github.com/friguzzi/3fb1006d2b81fd97d92858d7ddf5a284))

```
namespace Quantum.Search {


open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Oracles;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Arithmetic;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Characterization;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Arrays;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;


operation SprinklerAnc (queryRegister:  Qubit[],  target : Qubit) : Unit is Adj+Ctl 
{
    using (ancilla=Qubit[3 ])
    {
        X(queryRegister[2]);
        X(ancilla[0]);
        X(ancilla[1]);
        X(ancilla[2]);
    
        CCNOT(queryRegister[0],queryRegister[1],ancilla[0]);
        CCNOT(queryRegister[1],queryRegister[2],ancilla[1]);
        CCNOT(queryRegister[0],queryRegister[2],ancilla[2]);
        (Controlled X)([ancilla[0],ancilla[1],ancilla[2],queryRegister[3]],target);
        CCNOT(queryRegister[0],queryRegister[2],ancilla[2]);
        CCNOT(queryRegister[1],queryRegister[2],ancilla[1]);
        CCNOT(queryRegister[0],queryRegister[1],ancilla[0]);

        X(ancilla[2]);
        X(ancilla[1]);
        X(ancilla[0]);
        X(queryRegister[2]);

    }
}

operation ApplyMarkingOracleAsPhaseOracle (markingOracle : ((Qubit[], Qubit) => Unit is Adj+Ctl),  register : Qubit[] ) :  Unit is Adj+Ctl 
{
    
    using (target = Qubit()) 
    {
        // Put the target into the |-⟩ state
        X(target);
        H(target);
            
        // Apply the marking oracle; since the target is in the |-⟩ state,
        // flipping the target if the register satisfies the oracle condition will apply a -1 factor to the state
        markingOracle(register, target);
            
        // Put the target back into |0⟩ so we can return it
        H(target);
        X(target);
    }
}


// The Grover iteration
operation GroverIteration (register : Qubit[], oracle : ((Qubit[],Qubit) => Unit is Adj+Ctl)) : Unit is Ctl+Adj
{
    
    ApplyMarkingOracleAsPhaseOracle(oracle,register);
    ApplyToEachCA(H, register);
    using (ancilla = Qubit()){
            (ControlledOnInt(0, X))(register, ancilla); // Bit flips the ancilla to |1⟩ if register is |0...0⟩   
            Z(ancilla);                                 // Ancilla phase (and therefore whole register phase) becomes -1 if above condition is satisfied
            
            (ControlledOnInt(0, X))(register, ancilla); // Puts ancilla back in |0⟩  
    } 
    Ry(2.0 * PI(), register[0]);
    ApplyToEachCA(H, register);
}    


operation Search() : Result[] 
{
    
    using (reg=Qubit[4 ])
    {


  H(reg[0]);
  H(reg[1]);
  H(reg[2]);
  H(reg[3]);
  for (i in 1 ..2) {
  GroverIteration(reg, SprinklerAnc);
  }
  let state = MultiM(reg);

  ResetAll(reg);
  return state;
  }

}
}
```

with driver

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Quantum.Search
{
class Driver
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var qsim = new QuantumSimulator())
        {
            IDictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                IQArray<Result> res = QMPE.Run(qsim).Result;
                string s = Convert.ToString(res);
                int result;
                if (dict.TryGetValue(s, out result))
                {
                    dict.Remove(s);
                    dict.Add(s, result + 1);
                }
                else
                {

                    dict.Add(s, 1);
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine($"Res:{s}");

            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

It should search for the solutions of the 3 bits formula (not reg[0] or reg[2]) and (not reg[1](https://gist.github.com/friguzzi/3fb1006d2b81fd97d92858d7ddf5a284) or reg[2]) and (not reg[0] or not reg[1](https://gist.github.com/friguzzi/3fb1006d2b81fd97d92858d7ddf5a284)) and reg[3]. This formula has 4 solutions: 0001, 0011, 0111 and 1011. However, the distribution over the solutions that I get in 1000 execution is

```
Key: [One,One,One,Zero], Value: 57
Key: [One,One,Zero,Zero], Value: 63
Key: [Zero,One,One,One], Value: 58
Key: [Zero,One,One,Zero], Value: 74
Key: [One,Zero,One,One], Value: 70
Key: [One,Zero,One,Zero], Value: 70
Key: [Zero,Zero,One,Zero], Value: 76
Key: [One,Zero,Zero,One], Value: 47
Key: [Zero,Zero,Zero,Zero], Value: 79
Key: [Zero,One,Zero,Zero], Value: 66
Key: [One,One,One,One], Value: 52
Key: [Zero,Zero,Zero,One], Value: 55
Key: [One,Zero,Zero,Zero], Value: 58
Key: [Zero,One,Zero,One], Value: 58
Key: [Zero,Zero,One,One], Value: 63
Key: [One,One,Zero,One], Value: 54
```

so basically a uniform distribution over the whole set of 16 configurations. I don't understand why the solution of the equations are not getting higher frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: for this problem the optimal number of iterations is 1 - change the loop range to do just one iteration and the output will switch to showing only the solutions to the problem:

```
Key: [Zero,Zero,One,One], Value: 255
Key: [Zero,Zero,Zero,One], Value: 251
Key: [Zero,One,One,One], Value: 233
Key: [One,Zero,One,One], Value: 261
```

---

The general formula for the number of solutions is $\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{\frac{N}{M}}$, where $N = 16$ and $M = 4$, gives us $\frac{\pi}{2} \approx 1.5$, which can be rounded either up or down.

If we look at the derivation of the formula, however, we'll see that the square root is an approximation made assuming that $M << N$, and the optimal number of iterations is $>> 1$. The exact formula is $\frac12 \big( \frac{\pi}{2\arcsin \sqrt{\frac{M}{N}}}-1\big)$, which will give us $\arcsin \sqrt{\frac{M}{N}} = \arcsin 0.5 = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and the optimal number of iterations equal to 1.

You can see the visual derivation of the formula in [this slide deck](https://github.com/microsoft/GHC19-GroverSearch/blob/master/GHC19-IntroToQuantumComputing-Grover.pptx) - it shows where these assumptions come from and how they affect the result.